# How to navigate between pages in windows universal app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I am creating a Quiz program which contains many subjects. But I struck at the following stage. I created many pages and want to load them based on the subject selected. But I don't know how to make it.

Here is what I wanted.

[image]

Here Play,Settings and Exit are buttons in main screen. Once you click Play it will show you different subjects available. Once you select the subjects you have different options too.

at first I created Single page and I used grids with hide and show options. But its kind of buggy. So I created pages but I don't know how to navigate between the pages.

How can I achieve it.?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187344.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I will start now. If I have some problems I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ajit,

Yes you can navigate between Pages using  :

```
 currentFrame.Navigate(typeof(NextPage));
```

If currentPage is not this, you can find it the following helper class.
It allows to navigate, even from a ViewModel class :

```
public class NavigationExtension
{
    public static void Navigate(Type typeOfPage)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Window window = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current;
        if (window != null)
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame frame = window.Content as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                frame.Navigate(typeOfPage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go to another page and don't want to come back,
use this code:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Your Page Name));
```